# What are the best options for source control integrated with visual studio (2017), small team, multiple projects?

Tags: git, visual-studio, svn, version-control

What are your thoughts, suggestions, and recommendations for source control for the following environment?

MUST have Visual Studio integration!
Major Languages used: Visual Basic, SQL, C#
Possible other languages: Python, ASP MVC, others
Team size: small (currently 2 and probably won't change in the near future)
Organization: Not for profit, 500 employees, small IT department

Comment: Questions requesting tool recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As of Visual Studio 2013 Update 1, Git is included in the IDE by default. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Visual-Studio

I've used Git on teams as small as 1 and up to 10 people and never had any real issue with it.

In my experience, version control systems come down to preference. Here is a comparison of multiple version control systems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version-control_software#General_information

Answer (score -1):

Now that Git took the world of Version control tools by storm, you should have a really good reason to not choose it.

And there is not a lot of reasons.

Learn to use it, that will surely be a knowledge that you will use elsewhere. Especially now that a lot of libraries, tools and frameworks are developed in open source on git forges (GitHub, Bitbuckets,...)